# How to target label based on it's text value using CSS alone

Tags: html, css

In this checkbox label, I need to rename 'Users in year level/s' to 'Students in year level/s'.
Ideally I would use the id="audience-select-users" however, there are other identical uses of this ID on the site which I do not want to rename. I only have access to write custom CSS.

Is there a way to select the label based on it having the text 'Users in year level/s' in it?

[image]

```html
<fieldset class="checklist border-none" style="">
  <ul class="option-list">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="audience-select-users">
      <label for="audience-select-users">
      Users in year level/s
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

The only other unique item is the text under this a if there is any way to leverage that?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this is not the best practice, but if you don't have any other option you can try this:

```css
label[for="audience-select-users"] {
   position:relative; font-size:0px;
}
label[for="audience-select-users"]:after{
  Content:'Students in year level/s';
  position:absolute;
  font-size:15px;
  width:150px;
  
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="checklist border-none" style="">
  <ul class="option-list">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="audience-select-users">
      <label for="audience-select-users">
      Users in year level/s
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Example 2->
You can use unique input id to target the label..

```
#audience-select-users + label[for="audience-select-users"]
```

```css
#audience-select-users + label[for="audience-select-users"] {
   position:relative; font-size:0px;
}
#audience-select-users + label[for="audience-select-users"]:after{
  Content:'Students in year level/s';
  position:absolute;
  font-size:15px;
  width:150px;
  
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="checklist border-none" style="">
  <ul class="option-list">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="audience-select-users">
      <label for="audience-select-users">
      Users in year level/s
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. Please note I am unable to target the label[for="audience-select-users"] and change the content in this way because there are three other instances of label with the same "for" name with different values I do not want to adjust. For this reason, the only chance I have is targeting the existing content of the label, if that is possible, which is unique, i.e. if label.Content:" Users in year level/s" set font size 0 and add an after content.

Comment: We cannot directly target the text with CSS, I have added an Example 2 in the code where we can target the label using the sibling  input  and I assume that the id on the input is unique  ..

Comment: Hi. Thanks for having another go. This is the problem, the id on the input is not unique and the developers refuse to change it to be.

Comment: then those developers are practicing bad code techniques

Comment: yes I agree and it's very frustrating.